# How to use a scrollbar to change the value of a text box

Tags: vb.net

I have a scrollbar and I would like the scroll bar to change the value of txtRangeSpread textbox by 10 if I scroll to the right and by -10 if I scroll to the left.

Can I do this?

Comment: Hi there, Is this for desktop or web?

Comment: Thanks, this is for a desktop. I am working on a windows form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumed it HScrollbar1

```
HSCrollBar1.Maximum = 19
HSCrollBar1.Minimum = -10
HSCrollBar1.SmallChange = 1
```

And changedvalue event

```
Private Sub HScrollBar1_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles HScrollBar1.ValueChanged
    txtRangeSpread.Text = Format(HScrollBar1.Value)
End Sub
```

To link both textbox and scrollbar .. maybe you can do that in form load event or activate event or maybe button click event ..

```
txtRangeSpread.Text = "0"
HScollBar1.Value = val(txtRangeSpread.Text)
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I make it preserve the value of txtRangeSpread. I want to type a number and make sure that that number is then incremented. Right now it's replacing the value with the scrollbar event.

Comment: @user2494051 .. it's updated .. don't forget to vote this as the answer if this helps you .. :P ..

Answer (score 0):

See here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbar.scroll.aspx
And here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrolleventargs.aspx

1. Create an event handler for the scroll event of your scroll bar.
2. The eventargs has arguments for NewValue and OldValue. Checking which one is larger will tell you which way the user is scrolling.
3. Update your textbox accordingly.

Although some issues you may face are that event will be fired for any scroll event (e.g. drag or click), so you may get values outside of ranges that you are expecting.